# Creating custom credits using add_filter

Tags: php, html, wordpress

As far as I understand I can use `add_filter('hook', 'my_custom_credits');` to replace default credits with a custom one. I know how to create my_custom_credits function and it's working.

But I'm not sure how to find hook in someone's code. Do I need to create it or I just use some id?

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer credits
 *
 */
?>
<div id="footer__credits" class="footer__credits" <?php czr_fn_echo('element_attributes') ?>>
  <p class="czr-copyright">
    <span class="czr-copyright-text">&copy;&nbsp;<?php echo esc_attr( date('Y') ) ?>&nbsp;</span><a class="czr-copyright-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo() ) ?>"><?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo() ) ?></a><span class="czr-rights-text">&nbsp;&ndash;&nbsp;<?php _e( 'All rights reserved', 'customizr') ?></span>
  </p>
  <p class="czr-credits">
    <span class="czr-designer">
      <span class="czr-wp-powered"><span class="czr-wp-powered-text"><?php _e( 'Powered by', 'customizr') ?>&nbsp;</span><a class="czr-wp-powered-link fab fa-wordpress" title="<?php _e( 'Powered by WordPress', 'customizr' ) ?>" href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'https://wordpress.org/', 'customizr' ) ); ?>" target="_blank"></a></span><span class="czr-designer-text">&nbsp;&ndash;&nbsp;<?php printf( __('Designed with the %s', 'customizr'), sprintf( '<a class="czr-designer-link" href="%1$s" title="%2$s">%2$s</a>', esc_url( CZR_WEBSITE . 'customizr' ), __('Customizr theme', 'customizr') ) ); ?></span>
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: The code has to have a "hookable" function for you to filter. You can't just use `add_filter()` on any code. If you have access to the template file can you not just edit the HTML directly?

Comment: I can and I edited it and it was working. I was just wondering if it is possible to make it using hooks. If you can explain how to add a hookable function or just give me a link to example of using it I will be happy.

Comment: I would check out https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/filters/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/. If your HTML above is not written out with a function you will not be able to mod it with an `add_filter()` call.